# Parse string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, timespan

I have some strings of xxh:yym format where xx is hours and yy is minutes like "05h:30m". What is an elegant way to convert a string of this type to TimeSpan?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to work, though it is a bit hackish:

```
TimeSpan span;


if (TimeSpan.TryParse("05h:30m".Replace("m","").Replace("h",""), out span))
            MessageBox.Show(span.ToString());
```

Comment: I would suggest using perhaps `TimeSpan.TryParse("hh'h:'mm'm'", out span)` for a cleaner and more robust solution

Comment: Except when the string is 25h:30m

Comment: @fubo any solution ***not limited*** ?

Comment: _If you need to validate that the input string is a valid time-of-day (>= 00:00 and < 24:00), then you should consider this instead_:  `DateTime.TryParseExact("07:35", "HH:mm"` view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369059/how-to-convert-string-0735-hhmm-to-timespan

Answer (score 7):

`DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` lets you specify the exact format of the input. After you get the `DateTime`, you can grab the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` which is a `TimeSpan`.

In the absence of `TimeSpan.TryParseExact`, I think an 'elegant' solution is out of the mix.

@buyutec As you suspected, this method would not work if the time spans have more than 24 hours.

Comment: [TimeSpan.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) was added in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Are [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx) and [TimeSpan.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparse.aspx) not options?  If you aren't using an "approved" format, you'll need to do the parsing manually.  I'd probably capture your two integer values in a regular expression, and then try to parse them into integers, from there you can create a new TimeSpan with its constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here'e one possibility:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(s.Remove(2, 1).Remove(5, 1));
```

And if you want to make it more elegant in your code, use an extension method:

```
public static TimeSpan ToTimeSpan(this string s)
{
  TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(s.Remove(2, 1).Remove(5, 1));
  return t;
}
```

Then you can do

```
"05h:30m".ToTimeSpan();
```

Comment: What's about `TimeSpan.TryParse("hh'h:'mm'm'", out span)` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26769/206730

Answer (score 2):

From another thread:

[How to convert xs:duration to timespan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804/how-to-convert-xs-duration-to-timespan-in-vb-net/63219#63219)