# Parse YouTube duration ISO 8601

Tags: c#, datetime, youtube-api, date-format

How can I parse the youtube duration format which I believe is ISO 8601

This request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=Kdgt1ZHkvnM&part=contentDetails&key={API_KEY}
```

Returns

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"QVyS2yjpsZ-tKkk4JvgYeO_YkzY/Do26Zx0a-KfdN4FPvoMAgqiFNRA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"QVyS2yjpsZ-tKkk4JvgYeO_YkzY/yZ-09PZbpkEHSEcQeekJuGOCbJY\"",
   "id": "Kdgt1ZHkvnM",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT20M1S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Is there a library that parses this format "**PT20M1S**" for .Net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148885/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript-no here its solved

Comment: ... and here is a solution for .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804/how-to-convert-iso-8601-duration-to-timespan-in-vb-net

Comment: @Findus thanks mate, works fine. Strange that it would only exist in the xml namespace...

Comment: You can see related question.
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093071/convert-iso-8601-time-format-into-normal-time-duration

Answer (score 19):

Yes, YouTube uses ISO 8601 duration format, for more you can check it here [Wiki ISO 8601 duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

So what you need to do is to use the following code (of course in a proper context, when you will parse the XML), but you can get the idea:

```
TimeSpan youTubeDuration = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("PT20M1S");
```

Comment: Not a problem for the OP, since a YouTube video is unlikely to last months, but those finding this answer by searching for "ISO 8601 duration" should note the problem with months in using `XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760821/1536933