# How to parse string with hours greater than 24 to TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, timespan

How to parse string like 30:15 to TimeSpan in C#? 30:15 means 30 hours and 15 minutes.

```
string span = "30:15";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(
    Convert.ToDouble(span.Split(':')[0])).
  Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(
    Convert.ToDouble((span.Split(':')[1]))));
```

This does not seem too elegant.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760/c-parse-string-to-timespan) (duplicate).

Comment: does it need to support localization? (eg. 30.15 according to language settings)

Comment: Format will be always hh:mm but hh may happen to be > 24.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're certain that the format will always be "HH:mm" then try something like this:

```
string span = "35:15";
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(span.Split(':')[0]),    // hours
                           int.Parse(span.Split(':')[1]),    // minutes
                           0);                               // seconds
```

Comment: this does not work with a negative timespan (-35:15 would result in -34:45)

Comment: well c# TimeSpan works but how would you store this value in MSSQL ? Time(7) doesn´t work and string would not be that nice.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Luke's answer:

```
String span = "123:45";
Int32 colon = span.IndexOf(':');
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(Int32.Parse(span.Substring(0, colon)),
                                 Int32.Parse(span.Substring(colon + 1)), 0);
```

Obviously it assumes the original string is well-formed (composed of two parts separated by colon and parsable to an integer number).

Comment: I reckon Luke's one handles > 99 doesn't it?

Comment: @Erik, @jlp: Yes, mine handles hours greater than 99 just fine, although my original answer didn't (before I edited it half an hour ago). Maybe Erik was looking at the old answer.

Comment: @Luke: Yup! Exactly as you replied here ;)

Comment: @ErikBurigo Your solution doesn't work, if span is "99:00" then the strings you send to the Parse functions will be "9" and ":00" as i just tested in my code, .net 4.5. Here's the code: http://www.codesend.com/view/6ac57c0773c29b021a12fc91007d79a6/

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a simple method that I devised a long time ago and just posted today to my blog:

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    static int[] weights = { 60 * 60 * 1000, 60 * 1000, 1000, 1 };

    public static TimeSpan ToTimeSpan(this string s)
    {
        string[] parts = s.Split('.', ':');
        long ms = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length && i < weights.Length; i++)
            ms += Convert.ToInt64(parts[i]) * weights[i];
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
    }
}
```

This can handle a lot more situations than the simpler solutions provided before, but has its own shortcomings. I discuss it further [here](http://feliperochamachado.com.br/blog/?p=114).

Now, if you're in .NET 4 you can shorten the ToTimeSpan implementation to:

```
public static TimeSpan ToTimeSpan(this string s)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(s.Split('.', ':')
        .Zip(weights, (d, w) => Convert.ToInt64(d) * w).Sum());
}
```

You can even make it an one-liner if you don't mind using horizontal screen state...

Comment: The solution is OK if the problem is exactly as described in the question. But if the TimeSpan string value is like "1.06:00:00", this solution fails. Unfortunately the link that explains the shortcomings is not working. Meybe this issue is discussed there.

Comment: @Florian I'm moving my blog to a new (and better) host, that's why its offline for now! It does not support days, only hours. So, if you want 24 + 6hours, you'll have to use 30:00:00. The idea was to avoid using days altogether. The shortcomings have more to do with not supporting negative values...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Lukes answer, with a lot more code and room for improvement. BUT it deals with negatives Hours ("-30:15") aswell, so maybe it can help someone.

```
public static double GetTotalHours(String s)
    {
        bool isNegative = false;
        if (s.StartsWith("-"))
            isNegative = true;

        String[] splitted = s.Split(':');
        int hours = GetNumbersAsInt(splitted[0]);
        int minutes = GetNumbersAsInt(splitted[1]);

        if (isNegative)
        {
            hours = hours * (-1);
            minutes = minutes * (-1);
        }
        TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
        return t.TotalHours;
    }

public static int GetNumbersAsInt(String input)
        {
            String output = String.Empty;
            Char[] chars = input.ToCharArray(0, input.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsNumber(chars[i]) == true)
                    output = output + chars[i];
            }
            return int.Parse(output);
        }
```

usage

```
double result = GetTotalHours("30:15");
double result2 = GetTotalHours("-30:15");
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Jan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028628/9924249)

.NET 5

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 1 number : hours    "0" to "0:0:0" ,    "-1" to "-01:00:00"
    /// 2 numbers : hours, minutes    "1:2" to "01:02:00"
    /// 3 numbers : hours, minutes, seconds    "1:2:3" to "01:02:03"
    /// 4 numbers : days, hours, minutes, seconds    "1:2:3:4" to "1.02:03:04"
    /// Any char can be used as separator.    "1,2 3aaaa4" to "1.02:03:04"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeSpanString"></param>
    /// <param name="ts"></param>
    /// <returns>true : conversion succeeded</returns>
    public static bool GetTimeSpan(string timeSpanString, ref TimeSpan ts)
    {

        bool isNegative = timeSpanString.StartsWith("-"); // "-1:2:3" is true
        var digitsString = Regex.Replace(timeSpanString, "[^0-9]", " "); // "-1:2:3" to " 1 2 3" 
        var s = digitsString.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // "1","2","3"

        int days = 0;
        int hours = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int seconds = 0;

        switch (s.Length)
        {
            case 1:
                hours = int.Parse(s[0]);
                break;

            case 2:
                hours = int.Parse(s[0]);
                minutes = int.Parse(s[1]);
                break;

            case 3:
                hours = int.Parse(s[0]);
                minutes = int.Parse(s[1]);
                seconds = int.Parse(s[2]);
                break;

            case 4:
                days = int.Parse(s[0]);
                hours = int.Parse(s[1]);
                minutes = int.Parse(s[2]);
                seconds = int.Parse(s[3]);
                break;

            default:
                return false; //no digits or length > 4
        }

        if (isNegative)
        {
            ts = new TimeSpan(-days, -hours, -minutes, -seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            ts = new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

[TimeSpanHelper](https://github.com/mikihiro-t/TimeSpanHelper)
Convert TimeSpan to over 24 hours number. TimeSpan Converter, Rule for TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would use `TimeSpan.ParseExact` where a specific format is required. But the only hours formats that can be specified are as parts of days (see [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)).

Therefore you will need to do the work yourself:

```
string input = "30:24";
var parts = input.Split(':');
var hours = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
var minutes = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
var result = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
```

(But with some error checking.)

The three integer constructor of timespan allows hours >= 24 overflowing into the days count.