# TimeSpan will not parse some strings

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I'm not sure what's going on here, but it will accept some timespans, but not others. Can someone show me a way to check for a vaild time span in this format 99:59:59.

```
//50:30:00 is bad
//50:20:00 is good

try
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
    ts = TimeSpan.Parse("50:30:00");
}
catch //(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("bad time span");
}
```

Comment: `50:30:00` is bad while `50:20:00` is good ? doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse string with hours greater than 24 to TimeSpan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728321/how-to-parse-string-with-hours-greater-than-24-to-timespan)

Comment: I saw that, but I thought there's a chance this is a bug, so I decided to post it.

Comment: not a bug. it's the design of the class `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I mean that 50:30:00 will throw the exception while 50:20:00 will not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the `Timespan.Parse` method assumes that the time is int the format `Days:Hours:Minutes`. Since you can't have more than 24 hours in a day, it throws when the `Hours` component is greater than 24.

I have to admit I'm a bit surprised that `Timespan.Parse` won't do the conversion for you. I have a hunch it has something to do with the fact that not all days are 24 hours long.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it will accept 48:00:00 or 50:20:00 though. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Sure it does. `48:00:00` is read as "48 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes" (legal). `50:20:00` is read as "50 days, 20 hours, 0 minutes" (legal). `50:30:00` is read as "50 days, 30 hours, 0 minutes" (not legal). Days can't have 30 hours in them, so it throws and exception.

Comment: Ah thanks for that I understand how it's working now. I couldn't understand it.