# Parse a TimeSpan greater than 24 hours?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this function:

```
  public static decimal Hours(string s)
    {    
        return (decimal)TimeSpan.Parse(s).TotalHours + 0.005M;
    }
```

The format is Hours:Minutes, ex: 30:20, or 10:17. It fails if I write give it say 25:03 or 30:20 since it is over 24 hours. Is there a way I can have it parse something > 23:59 ?
Simply put, if my string is 30:30, this function needs to return 30.5.

Comment: Tried the format "1.02:03:04.005" (1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 4 seconds, 5 milliseconds)?

Comment: Yes there is a way..but I think that you are using the TimeSpan Check incorrectly, you should check it off of `TimeSpan's .TotalHours` property, you need to compare it to a current DateTime in regards to `TimeSpan`

Comment: The string I provide is h:m and it needs to work with that.

Comment: It fails because 30 is invalid value for an hour. Valid values are 0 to 23.

Comment: I understand, but how can I do this for hours > 24? I also use timespan to validate user input.

Comment: Looks like you want to pass it 1 day, 6 hours, 30 minutes.... if you already have 30:30 then I guess you know what the total hours are.

Comment: But the USER writes in 30:20... I cannot change that.

Comment: Try looking at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728321/how-to-parse-string-with-hours-greater-than-24-to-timespan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done using standard `TimeSpan.Parse()` method, but you can do that:

```
public static decimal Hours(string s)
{
    decimal r;
    if (decimal.TryParse(s, out r))
        return r;

    var parts = s.Split(':');
    return (decimal)new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]),0).TotalHours;
}
```