# HH:MM:SS format getting converted to days instead of hours

Tags: c#, timespan

if it's 01:00:00 it gets 1 hour correct. Even 15 hours-->15:00:00 converts. However 24:00:00 will count as 24 days. I want 600:00:00 for 600 hours not days.

```
Console.WriteLine("\n2.Enter the time");
var tmp = TimeSpan.Parse(Console.ReadLine()).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  If you want a user to just enter hours, why not just take whatever int they type in and create a new TimeSpan object yourself with the number of hours they enter

Comment: TimeSpan.ParseExact

Comment: @Steve: I don't believe that allows you to specify a value of more than 23 for the hours part.

Comment: What is the thing with the `TotalSeconds`, when you expect to get _hours_?

Comment: @schlonzo: You misunderstood. He's not expecting hours as the output of `TotalSeconds`. He's expecting the input to be parsed as a 24 hour timespan (86400 sec) instead of a 24 day timespan (2073600 sec). What he does with the timespan after parsing it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: There's no such time format, just like there's no format that accepts 13 months in a date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. What you want to enter is absolute hours. There is no format string for parsing that. Hours can only be between 0 and 23.

You will need to parse the input yourself into `Int32` variables and pass them to the [timespan constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bk8a3558(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ... as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728321/how-to-parse-string-with-hours-greater-than-24-to-timespan

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks!