# How to subtract time (HHH:MM)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, time, datetime-format

I want to Subtract two time strings that I read from an excel sheet, for example `150:24` and `124:30`.

The time format is HHH:MM in the excel sheet. How can I subtract these two strings in C#?

I can not illustrate the data format! also I can not write true code for this issue.

Comment: What is HHH:MM? And how the time is represented as 150:24?

Comment: @viveknuna this is probably not a time-of-day but a period of time, 150 hours plus 24 minutes.

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728321/how-to-parse-string-with-hours-greater-than-24-to-timespan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `calculate the times difference based on minutes`. Then convert to any format you want...

```
var s1 = "150:24".Split(':');
var s2 = "124:30".Split(':');

var diffMinutes= int.Parse(s1[0]) * 60 + int.Parse(s1[1]) - int.Parse(s2[0]) * 60 - int.Parse(s2[1]);
Console.WriteLine("difference in minutes: " +diffMinutes);  
//difference in minutes: 1554

Console.WriteLine("difference in HHH:MM: "+ diffMinutes/60 + ":"+diffMinutes%60); 
//difference in HHH:MM: 25:54

TimeSpan t= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(result);
Console.WriteLine(t); 
//1.01:54:00
```

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan.Parse` unfortunately does not work is the hour part is > 23. But of course it is possible to split on the ':', convert the hour and minute parts to integers separately and construct a TimeSpan from it:

```
public static TimeSpan ParseHoursAndMinutes(string s)
{
  // NOTE: no error checking!
  var parts = s.Split(':');
  var hours = int.Parse(parts[0]);
  var minutes = int.Parse(parts[1]);
  return new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
}

var diff = ParseHoursAndMinutes("150:24") - ParseHoursAndMinutes("124:30");
Console.WriteLine(diff); // => 1.01:54:00
```