# How to Convert string "07:35" (HH:MM) to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, timespan

I would like to know if there is a way to convert a 24 Hour time formatted string to a TimeSpan.

Right now I have a "old fashion style":

```
string stringTime = "07:35";
string[] values = stringTime.Split(':');

TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(values[0], values[1], 0);
```

Comment: Use TimeSpan.Parse.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to TimeSpan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760/parse-string-to-timespan)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

## Data Types

For the string `"07:35"` given in the question, there are three possible data types to choose from:

### `TimeSpan`

- Primarily intended for a duration of elapsed time.
- Sometimes used for a time-of-day, especially prior to .NET 6.
- Range: `-10675199.02:48:05.4775808` to `10675199.02:48:05.4775807`
- Magnitudes of 24 hours or larger are represented in terms of standard (24 hour) days, which are separated by a period in the default string representation.
- Negative values represent moving backwards in time.

### `TimeOnly`

- Intended for a time-of-day value, without any date component.
- Range: `00:00:00.000000` to `23:59:59.9999999`
- Available since .NET 6.  For older .NET, consider a polyfill library such as [`Portable.System.DateTimeOnly`](https://github.com/OlegRa/System.DateTimeOnly).

### `DateTime`

- Primarily intended for a date combined with a time.
- Range: `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999`
- Sometimes used for representing time-only values, by using an arbitrary date such as `0001-01-01` or `2000-01-01`, etc.  When doing so, it's important to disregard the date in all usages.  Generally, this was done in older software to support parsing am/pm components, but is no longer necessary since .NET 6.

## Parsing

### Methods

All three data types support the following methods:

- `Parse` - Attempts to parse using a variety of known formats.  Throws an exception if parsing does not succeed.
- `TryParse` - Like `Parse`, but returns `false` if the parsing does not succeed.  Useful for validation logic.
- `ParseExact` - Attempts to parse using a specific format.  Throws an exception if parsing does not succeed.
- `TryParseExact` - Like `ParseExact`, but returns `false` if parsing does not succeed.  Useful for validation logic.

### Format Specifiers (tokens)

The `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` methods require a format specification, which can be either in a standard form represented by a a single character, or a custom form represented by multiple characters.  The format strings differ by data type.

- `TimeOnly` and `DateTime` use the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) date and time format strings.

  - `"07:35"` can be parsed with the custom `"HH:mm"` format in all cultures, including the `InvariantCulture`.
  - `"07:35"` can also be parsed with the standard `"t"` format in many cultures, including the `InvariantCulture`.
- `TimeSpan` uses the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) time span format strings.

  - `"07:35"` can be parsed with the custom `@"hh\:mm"` (or `"hh\\:mm"`) format in most cultures, including the `InvariantCulture`.
  - `"07:35"` can also be parsed with the standard `"c"` or `"g"` formats in many cultures, including the `InvariantCulture`.

### Examples

I'll demonstrate both `TimeSpan` and `TimeOnly`.  (Generally speaking, `DateTime` is no longer needed for such strings.)  In all cases, be sure to import both `System` and `System.Globalization` in your using statements, unless you're already importing them implicitly.

- Flexible parsing (using current culture):

  ```cs
  TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.Parse("07:35");
  ```

  ```cs
  TimeOnly time = TimeOnly.Parse("07:35");
  ```
- Fixed parsing (performant, using invariant culture):

  ```cs
  TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.ParseExact("07:35", @"hh\:mm", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  ```

  ```cs
  TimeOnly time = TimeOnly.ParseExact("07:35", "HH:mm", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  ```
- Flexible parsing for validation (using current culture):

  ```cs
  TimeSpan duration;
  if (!TimeSpan.TryParse("07:35", out duration))
  {
      // handle validation error
  }
  ```

  ```cs
  TimeOnly time;
  if (!TimeOnly.TryParse("07:35", out time))
  {
      // handle validation error
  }
  ```
- Fixed parsing for validation (performant, using invariant culture):

  ```cs
  TimeSpan duration;
  if (!TimeSpan.TryParseExact("07:35", @"hh\:mm", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out duration))
  {
      // handle validation error
  }
  ```

  ```cs
  TimeOnly time;
  if (!TimeOnly.TryParseExact("07:35", "HH:mm", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
  {
      // handle validation error
  }
  ```

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` is quite slow, `DateTime.TryParseExact` is miles quicker. My understanding is `TryParse` tries a set of patterns to see if any match, if the format you're after is at the bottom of that list, its a substantial overhead that is easily avoided

Comment: I can't parse a time over than 24 hours

Comment: @alansiqueira27 - `TimeSpan` can *represent* >= 24 hours, but as a string it treats them as "days".  So `ParseExact` etc. cannot parse them.  It would be nice if there was some other token to allow it, but alas there is not.  Instead one can parse such strings manually, such as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728321/how-to-parse-string-with-hours-greater-than-24-to-timespan).

Comment: what if its `7:35 AM` to TimeSpan

Comment: `TimeSpan.TryParseExact("7:35 AM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out TimeSpan startDate);` does not work

Comment: @Tonto - My original answer suggested `DateTime` for such a format, not `TimeSpan`.  Nonetheless, today I would recommend `TimeOnly` for such values.  I've revised the entire answer to cover this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse(stringTime);
```

With a newer .NET  you also have

```
TimeSpan ts;

if(!TimeSpan.TryParse(stringTime, out ts)){
     // throw exception or whatnot
}
// ts now has a valid format
```

This is the general idiom for parsing strings in .NET with the first version handling erroneous string by throwing FormatException and the latter letting the Boolean TryParse give you the information directly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `TimeSpan.Parse` to convert the string

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the time using the following code.

```
TimeSpan _time = TimeSpan.Parse("07:35");
```

But if you want to get the current time of the day you can use the following code:

```
TimeSpan _CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

The result will be:

```
03:54:35.7763461
```

With a object cantain the Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Ticks and etc.