# What is the best way to convert this format to timespan?

Tags: c#

I have a day time format like this "20.10:05:01". It reads as Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. How do I convert that to time span to get the total seconds or hours?

Comment: What's wrong with `TimeSpan.Parse`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Is this a DateTime datatype or is your "20.10:05:01 a string? Cause usually I would say a simple  `TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(string);` would be enough...

Comment: Check this SO on: [Convert string to TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369059/how-to-convert-string-0735-hhmm-to-timespan)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert string "07:35" (HH:MM) to TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369059/how-to-convert-string-0735-hhmm-to-timespan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `string` called `value` containing such value, you can do

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value,@"dd\.hh\.mm\:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

From there, you can use `timeSpan.TotalSeconds` or `timeSpan.TotalHours`;