# Convert Time with milliseconds to dateTime in c#

Tags: c#, time

I am trying to convert Time `string` to `DateTime` but can't.

Example: Time: **12:05:45.458** with milliseconds need to convert to time.

Any solution?

Comment: Do you mean you want today's date with that time?

Comment: Show the code you currently use.

Comment: A `DateTime`, as its name suggests, contains both a date and a time. Since you only have a time, what should be used for the date? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure you are not referring to TimeSpan? You may check it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369059/how-to-convert-string-0735-hhmm-to-timespan

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.ParseExact` should solve this

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("12:05:45.458", "HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime.ParseExtract` will parse the given time and convert to DateTime object with date as current date.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("12:05:45.458", "HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [`Timespan.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) here. Since you do not have any date component, it is not possible to unambiguously convert to a DateTime instance.

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution:

```
 string time = "12:05:45.458";
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Where goes the millisecond part in that? And I think it will fail with an exception anyway.

Comment: @TanveerBadar yes, forgot about seconds)

Comment: I'll retract my downvote, but we do basically have 3 identical answers now.

Comment: Mine still stands out as unique :P