# C# Convert List<string> to List<TimeSpan>

Tags: c#, list, timespan

I've seen examples of how to convert a `string` to a `TimeSpan`, here is one example:

[How to Convert string "07:35" (HH:MM) to TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369059/how-to-convert-string-0735-hhmm-to-timespan)

But what is the *most efficient* way to convert a `List<string>` to `List<TimeSpan>`?

I've tried something along these lines, but isn't working:

```
var result = new TimeSpan;

var appointmentStartTimesConverted = appointmentStartTimes
  .Select(i => result = TimeSpan.TryParse(i, out result))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: TryParse returns a bool. I think use `{ result=xx; return result;}`

Comment: don't use LINQ.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary close voting your answer, because opinion based ^^

Comment: `TryParse` returns bool. you cannot add bool in `TimeSpan`.  by doing this `result = TimeSpan.TryParse(i,out result)`

Comment: I dont think it should be closed. its not opinion based.

Comment: @nilsK Comments in not answers, it's a place for opinions.

Comment: @SeM Sure. But an answer would have helped too. And it wasn't an answer.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, I've used Lews answer but the non linq version by Dmitry is fine also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should do the job:

```
 var appointmentStartTimes = new List<string>{"7:45", "0:0","a"};

 var appointmentStartTimesConverted = appointmentStartTimes
   .Select(i =>
            {
                TimeSpan result;
                if(TimeSpan.TryParse(i, out result))
                    return new Nullable<TimeSpan>(result);          
                return null;        
            })
   .Where(x => x.HasValue)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Good spot.. but TryParse doesn't return a nullable.. fixed anyway

Comment: `x!=default(TimeSpan)` condition can be *dangerous*. What if we have `"0:0"` string to convert?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Third time charm?

Comment: `x=>x.HasValue` is quite OK, no side effects :)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for spotting that though :-)

Comment: To actually get `TimeStamp` and not `TimeStamp?`,  replace  `.Where(x => x.HasValue)` with  `.OfType<TimeSpan>()`

Comment: @Tewr I would imagine `HasValue` is a cheaper check than `OfType<TimeSpan>`

Comment: Yes, but I would also imagine that `GetValueOrDefault()` will be called at some point later on, unless he is converting for fun.. :)

Answer (score 4):

No Linq solution - a *simple loop* is enough:

```
 List<TimeSpan> result = new List<TimeSpan>(appointmentStartTimes.Count);

 foreach (var item in appointmentStartTime)
   if (TimeSpan.TryParse(item, out var span)) // out var - C# 7.0 feature
     result.Add(span);
```

Comment: This answer adresses the _most efficient_ emphasis by op. That said, the dual absence of brackets makes me feel naked.

Answer (score 1):

in  below code, I'm having a list of string (which is supposed to have `Timespan` string but it can hold any string)

so first I'm checking for the condition if it passes `TryParse` and only then I am converting particular string into `Timespan` and add it into List of `Timespan`

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();
str.Add("07:30");
str.Add("amit");
TimeSpan res = new TimeSpan();
List<TimeSpan> ts = str.Where(x => TimeSpan.TryParse(x, out res) != false).Select(y => res).ToList();
```

This will take care of invalid time span string.

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse` returns bool. Use `Parse` in try/catch block to ensure all values will be processed or use output parameter from TryParse

There is no need to declare local variable `result`.

```
var appointmentStartTimes = new List<string>();
//fill values here 

var appointmentStartTimesConverted = appointmentStartTimes
    .Select(i =>
        {
            try
            {
                return TimeSpan.Parse(i);
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(TimeSpan);
            }
        }
    ).ToList();

//anothey way
appointmentStartTimesConverted = appointmentStartTimes
    .Select(i =>
        {
            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(i, out var result))
                return result;

            return default(TimeSpan);
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something using Linq, but with an intermediate Function, like this:

```
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "7:35", "3:45", "0:23" };

        Func<string, TimeSpan> GetTS = (str) =>
        {
            TimeSpan.TryParse(str, out TimeSpan ts);
            return ts;
        };

        var tsLst = lst.Select(r => GetTS(r)).ToList();
```

Comment: this is not good. you get default values and you dont know if default value is legitimate result or a failure.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. At first I thought TimeSpan TryParse would have given a null value in case of failure. I give count it's not true. Thanks, @M.kazemAkhgary