# Converting string into Timespan for formats like '1h 0m'

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert this string into TimeSpan,

```
string input = "1h 0m";
string format = "%h %m"; // also tried "hh mm"
TimeSpan ts;
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, format, null, out ts);
```

But output each time I am getting is `00:00:00`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to TimeSpan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760/parse-string-to-timespan)

Comment: Did you try string format = "%hh %mm";?

Comment: string[] formats = { "m\m", "h\h\ m\m" };

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I want it to be dynamic and work with formats, don't want to split string etc..

Comment: @Mathematics Check out the first comment of the accepted answer - that's the way to go.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Just look at the 2nd comment on the same answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format is incorrect. This would work.

```
string input = "1h 0m";
string[] formats = { @"m\m", @"h\h\ m\m" };
TimeSpan ts;
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, formats, null, out ts);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] formats = { @"m\m", @"h\h\ m\m" };
```

Comment: These are not verbatim strings. Its missing `@` in beginnings. That or  escape them with additional `\`. Rest all fine.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal .. i just post ans for formality ... You already give the ans so i think no need of .. this...  they understand ...